# php mysql single record show

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry about the stupid question however I can't see/ not good enough to solve this:

I have a MYSQL db and a php form everything works but I can't get out only one record - probably syntax error:

```
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM massfelh WHERE user = $uname AND pass = md5($pword)"; - this is working
    $result = mysql_query($SQL); - this is too
    $catg = $result['categ']; - help
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); - this is ok too
    echo $catg; - for test and I can't print it on screen
```

DB structure: id, user, pass, categ

I only need the categ (either 1 or 0) but it just won't show on screen.

Any help would be appreciated - and please say I am stupid too:)

Update:

thank you for everyone of you!!!!!!! Helped me a lot. I have fount the best solution for my code however all the reply was correct. Thanks again hop this will help to some one how is just as beginner as me:) thank you again

Comment: what is the output of `echo $catg;`?? try `echo $num_rows;` and `print_r($catg);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This..

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM massfelh WHERE user = $uname AND pass = md5($pword)"; 
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $catg = $result['categ'];
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
    echo $catg;
```

Comment: thanks very much!!!!!!!! Helped a lot I changed the fetch bit with result1 and it did work.

Answer (score 1):

adding a `LIMIT 1` to your select is good practice if you expect just one row.

If you only want to select *categ* then only select it `SELECT categ FROM...`.
Then you could use `$catg = mysql_result($result, 0);`
http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL); - this is too
$catg   = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($catg);
```

`mysql_query` returns a resource. To fetch data you have to use some of next functions:
- mysql_fetch_row (returns result as numerical array)
- mysql_fetch_assoc (returns result as assoc array - keys of array are field's name in db table)
- mysql_fetch_array (returns both numerical and assoc results if you dont pass second parameter)

But it would have been better if you had used Mysqli extension or PDO_Mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you only need 'categ' just select that. Use var_dump on $result too.

```
SELECT categ FROM massfelh WHERE user = $uname AND pass = md5($pword)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not using any php function to get out put after executing query.

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$res   = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $res['columnName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM massfelh WHERE user = $uname AND pass = md5($pword)";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$catg   = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $num_rows.' rows matched';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($catg);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `mysql_fetch_assoc` there. It should be

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM massfelh WHERE user = $uname AND pass = md5($pword)";
$query = mysql_query($SQL);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$catg = $result['categ'];
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $catg;
```

Ofcourse, the query can also be `SELECT categ FROM massfelh WHERE user = $uname AND pass = md5($pword)`

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns a result resource, you need to pass this to a fetch function in order to access the returned data. For example:

```
$query = mysql_query($SQL);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$catg = $result['categ'];
```

Use of `mysql_` extensions is discouraged and the community has begun the deprecation process, you should have a read of the `mysql_query` documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php